# Why is Math.Round(3.13732294754486E-12, 2) zero?

Tags: c#

I want to do this:

```
var x = Math.Round(item.Distance.Value, 2)
```

The value of the distance is: `3.13732294754486E-12`.

The value is returned from `HttpClient` result.

The `x` will be zero. Why is this happening? I expect `3.14` for the result.

Comment: these seams to be a parsing problem.

Comment: Voting to close because this is a non-question. *"Why does 0.0000000000003 round to zero?"*

Comment: `3.13732294754486E-12` is a really small number, written without scientific notation it would be `0.0000000000313732294754486`. If I round a number that small a number to 2 decimal places it is approximately equivalent to `0`. In fact, anything as smaller than `0.005` is approximately `0` at two decimals places and this is much smaller than that.

Comment: This is a mathematics question, not a stackoverflow.com question.

Comment: Well how silly I was. I parsed the wrong location. It supposed to be the real location of me, but instead I parsed dummy location which located at the same place as the target. I was a bit confused because on the real site the correct distance between my real location was 3.13..... something too (what a coincidence) and this debugging value got me 3.1373.....E-12. So I kinda slipped knowing those 2 locations were not the same. Thank you, and yes please close this question

Answer (score 3):

As the comment notes, there may be a parsing problem. However, if we take it at face value...

The notation `E` is exponential notation. A lot of languages support it, including C#

`a E b = a x 10^b`, for example `2.1E2 = 2.1 x 10^2 = 2.1 x 100 = 210`

In your example we are multiplying 3.13... by `10^-12 = 0.000000000001`
or `0.0000000000031....`

`Math.Round(0.00000000000031...., 2)` is indeed zero.

Answer (score 2):

`3.13732294754486E-12` is [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) and means `3.13… × 10^-12` for the following number:

```
0.00000000000313732294754486
```

If you round that number to two digits after the stop, you get `0.00` which is zero. So the result you get is totally expected. If you want to round that to `3.13E-12`, then you could use string formatting for this:

```
string result = (3.13732294754486E-12).ToString("E2");
Console.WriteLine(result); // 3,14E-012
```